# Diagonalizing the sum of a matrix and a multiple of the identity matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose we have a matrix $A = B+\lambda I$, where $B\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, $I$ is the identity matrix and $\lambda\in \mathbb{R}$. If I know the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $B$, what can I say about the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $A$? Does it matter if $B$ is symmetric?

I tried a few matrices in MATLAB and it seems that the eigenvectors of $A$ are simply the eigenvectors of $B$ and the eigenvalues of $A$ are simply the eigenvalues of $B$ plus $\lambda$. Is this true and what is the reason for this?

Comment: Hint: $BX=\mu X$ if and only if $AX=(\mu+\lambda)X$.

Comment: @julien Ah thank you, how silly of me.

Comment: @RudevanNistelrooy Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).